# Configure a PicketLink Token.Consumer?

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-ee, token, picketlink

I am trying to implement token-based authentication in my Java EE 7 app using PicketLink 2.7.  I have based my code off of the picketlink-angularjs-rest quickstart found [here](https://github.com/pedroigor/picketlink-quickstarts/tree/master/picketlink-angularjs-rest).  I have successfully configured a `Token.Provider` to issue my tokens, and using the `SecurityConfigurationBuilder` I am able to configure PicketLink to authenticate users based on the presence of the token in the `Authorization` header.  However, I have also implemented a `Token.Consumer` to extract identity information from the token, and it is never called.  It appears as though PicketLink is just pulling account information from my JPA `IdentityStore`.  How do I go about telling PicketLink to use my `Token.Consumer` to gather this information?  My `Token.Consumer` validates a digital signature, etc. so it is important that it is being called.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else struggling with this, the answer is to call `setCredentialHandlerProperty(TokenCredentialHandler.TOKEN_CONSUMER, new MyTokenConsumer())` on your `IdentityConfigurationBuilder`.  That will set the necessary property and your `Token.Consumer` will be called when validating an authentication token.